# Union of specific prime ideals is not an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ with three prime ideals $P_1,P_2,P_3$ such that $P_i\subseteq P_j$ if and only if $i=j$. I want to show that the union of these prime ideals, which I denote $J$, is not an ideal of $R$.

Somehow I need to find two elements $x,y\in J$ such that $x+y\notin J$. Can someone help me out?

Comment: For the general case maybe you want to read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_avoidance_lemma).

Comment: By *Prime avoidance theorem*, (3.61 of *Sharp*'s book: *Steps in Commutative Algebra*), if $J$ is an ideal, then it will be one of $P_i$ s. and from its proof you can take the proof for your question.

Comment: one can just google "Prime avoidance theorem" + the comment says how one can reach  the proof.

Comment: @user1 If I understand well the OP wants a direct proof (which is more or less similar to the proof of the prime avoidance lemma), not to use some other result for proving the property.

Comment: I am more than content with the answer. Thank you^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_i\in P_i-(P_j\cup P_k)$. (Why there is such an element?) Then $$x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1\notin P_1\cup P_2\cup P_3.$$
(If you like can use $x_1x_2+x_3$ instead of $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1$.)